# change navbar color using vue3 and bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

This here is my Nav

```
 <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary navbar-expand-lg" 
data-bs-theme="dark"      :class="{'navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ' : useDarkNavbar, 'navbar-expand-lg bg-light' : !useDarkNavbar}"  >
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Vue</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li v-for="(page, index) in pages" class="nav-item" :key="index" >
            <a class="nav-link"
            :class ='{active : activePage == index  }'
            aria-current="page" 
            v-bind:href="page.link.url" 
            :title="`This is ${page.link.text} page`" 
            @click.prevent="activePage = index"
            >{{page.link.text}}</a>
          </li>
          <!-- <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li> -->
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success"
          @click.prevent="useDarkNavbar = !useDarkNavbar"
          >
            Toggle Navbar
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And this the form for the button,that when its clicked it changes the navbar color

```
<form class="d-flex">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success"
          @click.prevent="useDarkNavbar = !useDarkNavbar"
          >
            Toggle Navbar
          </button>
        </form>
```

And this is the vue

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
// template: '<h2>Hey there</h2>',
data(){//Options object
    return {
        useDarkNavbar:true,
        activePage : 0,
    pages : [
        { link : {text:'Home',url:'index.html'},
            pageTitle : 'Home page',
            content:'This is the home content'
        },
        {
            link : {text:'About',url:'about.html'},
            pageTitle : 'About page',
            content:'This is the about content'
        },
        {
            link : {text:'Contact',url:'contact.html'},
            pageTitle : 'Contact page',
            content:'This is the contact content'
        }
    ],

    }
} }) app.mount('body')
```

when the button is clicked it only shows the light theme and when clicked again to show the dark theme the navbar disappears.What can i do to fix it?

Comment: The Vue instance needs to be mounted to the component or related root component for it to have control over it.  `const app = Vue.createApp` is creating a new Vue instance that can only control the template and data declared within itself. If you're trying to work with multiple [SFCs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html) you don't use `createApp` for each one.  Have one instance mounted to a root component (usually App.vue), and all components should in some way be nested within that root.  Right now, your last code snippet is completely isolated from the rest of your code.

Comment: @yoduh i just did send the full vue code but it is mounted on the body

Comment: Ok.  It's not clear to me the architecture of your app then.  Is your nav and/or form in their own component file?  If it happens that all your code is in a single `.html` file, it should work.  See [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/VwVdQQG?editors=1010).  Maybe you can provide more missing information that can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems...

1. `useDarkNavbar` is in the parent/app not the navbar component. Use a prop to pass it through to the Navbar
2. The classes are all wrong. Where are you using `data-bs-theme="dark` and `bg-body-tertiary`? It will override whatever class logic is being updated
3. You need to use `navbar-dark` and `navbar-light` too. The control the foreground/text color the Navbar.

see: https://codeply.com/p/osdfIHq6lE

```
const navBar = {
  template: '#navBar',
  data() {
    return {
        activePage : 0,
        show: true,
        pages : [
            { link : {text:'Home',url:'index.html'},
                pageTitle : 'Home page',
                content:'This is the home content'
            },
            {
                link : {text:'About',url:'about.html'},
                pageTitle : 'About page',
                content:'This is the about content'
            },
            {
                link : {text:'Contact',url:'contact.html'},
                pageTitle : 'Contact page',
                content:'This is the contact content'
            }
        ],

    }
  },
  props: {
      useDark: Boolean
  },
}

Vue.createApp({
  components: {
      navBar
  },
  data() {
    return {
        useDarkNavbar: true
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

Comment: the ` data-bs-theme="dark` came with the bootstrap and the navbar-dark wasnt working.I edited the code

Comment: And so? ... what is the issue? I posted a working example